# i am making a simple calculator(+,-,*,/ and cls) how can i get two input strings and perform operation

Tags: javascript, android, string

i know how to add two strings but don't know how will i obtain which no user pressed and obtain their string something to do with `OnClick` ?

Comment: very unclear, plz elaborate..

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you please explain what you are attempting to achieve more clearly, preferably with some examples?  Thank you!

Comment: 1) get two inputs that user clicked on in the app eg 1 and 2  and +    2) get those clicked buttons and add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the id of the clicked button and adding it's string with the number it hab with something like that in your activity:

```
void methodCalledByOnClick(View v) {

  switch(v.getId()) {

  case R.id.btn_NrOne:
    editTextWhereNumbersHaveToBeDisplayed.setText(
        editTextWhereNumbersHaveToBeDisplayed.getText() + v.getText()
    );
    break;
  case R.id.btn_NrTwo:

    and so on...
  }

}
```

To get the Number for calculation out of the textEdit please have a look at te answer from Veer Shubhranshu Shrivastav.

Also: Please try to be more precise in future questions you may have!

Comment: thank you for  the help i got it now. im sorry its been only 3 days since i started learning android development :)

Comment: Not a problem. For me it's also just half a year. Make sure to have a look into all the great tutorials on developer.android.com.

Also accept the answer, that helped you here, that everyone knows, this is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Your question did not state whether this is for an android app or a HTML app. In case you are referring to an android app then I recommend going through the Android training. That explains the basics on how to access views etc.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, restrict the user to enter only numeric value in the Textbox.

In android `EditText` has a attribute `inputType` make it number. Then the user can only enter number. Then for thread-safe program check the ASCII value of the input between `48-54` (0-9)

Then you use

```
  EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit1);
  int num = Integer.parseInt(ed.getText);   ///You got the number.
```